# ArcGIS 10.1 Network Analyst shortest route starting from one specific point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, network-analyst

I would like to create the shortest route starting from one specific point in a network out of 12 different points. I know how to get the shortest route by clicking each point after the other to give arcgis the order. but what i wanna do is to just give the starting point and let arcgis calculate the best/shortest route out of all these points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the [Reorder Stops To Find Optimal Route](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//004700000045000000) option.

> By default, a route traverses stops in the order you define. However,
>   you can possibly shorten the route further by letting Network Analyst
>   find the best order. It will account for a variety of variables, such
>   as time windows. Another option is to preserve the origin and
>   destination while allowing Network Analyst to reorder the intermediary
>   stops.
>
> When you check this property, the route analysis changes from a
>   shortest-path problem to a traveling salesperson problem (TSP).

Create a Route network layer > open Layer Properties window.

[image]